# How can I format every other line to be merged with the line before it? (In Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup

I have been working with beautiful soup to extract data from website APIs for use in a fan site I am building.

I have extracted the data into text files however I am having trouble formatting it.

```
Charles Dance
Lord Tywin Lannister (S 02+)
Natalie Dormer
Queen Margaery Tyrell (S 02+)
Harry Lloyd
Viserys Targaryen (S 01)
Mark Addy
King Robert Baratheon (S 01)
Alfie Allen
Theon Greyjoy
Sean Bean
Lord Eddard Stark (S 01)
```

I have several text files like this for shows. 
I would like to have both the actor and character on the same line separated with commas for input into a database later.

```
Charles Dance , Lord Tywin Lannister (S 02+)
Natalie Dormer , Queen Margaery Tyrell (S 02+)
Harry Lloyd , Viserys Targaryen (S 01)
Mark Addy , King Robert Baratheon (S 01)
Alfie Allen , Theon Greyjoy
Sean Bean , Lord Eddard Stark (S 01)
```

If anyone could provide any assistance or pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

## Solved:

Many thanks to Tdelaney and wnnmaw . you da real MVPs

```
def readline(fp):
#Read a line from a file, strip new line and raise Indexerror
#on end of file
line = fp.readline()
if not line:
    raise IndexError()
return line.strip()

with open('Casts/GOTcast.txt') as in_file, open('GOTcastFIXED.txt', 'w') as out_file:
try:
    while True:
        out_file.write("%s, %s\n" % (readline(in_file), readline(in_file)))
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: Do you have the data in a list (one item per line) or already in a file? In a file, you could just delete every other \n.

Comment: That makes sense to me, yes its just a text file not a list thats why the below answer has stumped me a bit. How would you delete every other /n ? and also add a comma?

    `with open('Casts/GOTcast.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.read()`

thats how i'm reading the file atm

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work:

```
>>> lst = ["a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "C"]
>>> lines = [" , ".join(tup) for tup in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])]
>>> lines
['a , A', 'b , B', 'c , C']
```

You can read your text file like this:

```
with open("yourfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for such a prompt reply. ...

Now i'm just going to struggle a little bit turning my text file into a list.

Comment: I now was able to replace line breaks with commas using `text = str.replace(text, "\n", ",")` However I have been unable to successfully turn it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

So, you just want to read the file and combine every two lines into one. That's easy as long as you deal with a few details like stipping the new line character knowing when you've finished reading the file.

One way to solve this is to wrap the details in a function so that a simple for loop can do the rest.

```
def readline(fp):
    """Read a line from a file, strip new line and raise Indexerror
    on end of file"""
    line = fp.readline()
    if not line:
        raise IndexError()
    return line.strip()

with open('infile.txt') as in_file, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    try:
        while True:
            out_file.write("%s, %s\n" % (readline(in_file), readline(in_file)))
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Very grateful for your response, I wasn't 100% that I  could use "in_file" or any other text I had been using "f" for everything. 
after i discovered the missing parenthesis on the 3rd line from the bottom i succeeded many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the note, fixed the problem.