# scraping data from a dynamic graph using python+beautifulSoup4

Tags: python, graph, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to implement a data scraping task and extract data from a dynamic graph. The graph is update with time similar to what you would find if you look at the graph of a company's stock. I am using the requests and beautifulsoup4 library in python but I have only figured out how to scrape text and links data. Can't seem to figure out how i can get the values of the graph into a csv file

The graph in question can be found at - http://www.apptrace.com/app/instagram/id389801252/ranks/topfreeapplications/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oliver W. provided a good answer already, but using `requests` ([link here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) avoids having to note the network call and is overall a much nicer package than `urllib`.

If you wanna be a bit more flexible with your code, you can write a function that takes the country name and start and end date.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

def load_data(country='', start_date='2014-08-09', end_date='2014-11-1'):
    base = "http://www.apptrace.com/api/app/389801252/rankings/country/"
    extra = "?country={0}&start_date={1}&end_date={2}&device=iphone&list_type=normal&chart_subtype=iphone"
    addr = base + extra.format(country, start_date, end_date)

    page = requests.get(addr)
    json_data = page.json() #gets the json data from the page
    ranks = json_data['rankings'][0]['ranks']
    ranks = json.dumps(ranks)  #Ensures it has valid json format
    df = pd.read_json(ranks, orient='records')
    return df
```

Change things in the webpage to see what other values you can get from country (Canada is 'CAN' for example). The empty string is for the USA.

The df looks like this

```
    date        rank
0   2014-08-09  10
1   2014-08-10  10
2   2014-08-11  9
3   2014-08-12  8
4   2014-08-13  8
5   2014-08-14  7
6   2014-08-15  6
7   2014-08-16  8
```

With the pandas dataframe in hand, you can export to `csv`or combine many dataframes before you export

```
df = load_data()
df.to_csv("file_name.csv")
```

Comment: Also once the dataframe is loaded into csv it displays date as a datetime object ie 2014-08-09 0:00. I am trying to convert it to only date by using the date method but cant access the field. And I dont need the index how do I delete that

Comment: You might want to read up on the [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation. It also has a keyword argument `date_format` that you could use and the `index` argument, e.g. `df.to_csv("file_name.csv", date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index=False)`.
Also, don't forget to upvote the answers that were useful and/or to accept the one that helped you most in case your [question was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) satisfactorily.

Comment: @aamir23  That "static" chart works in the exact same way. The JSON data is behind [this link](http://www.apptrace.com/api/app/389801252/sentiments), which you can find in the exact same way I described before.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response Oliver. Yes I figured that out. I am now trying to list all the apps and their respective developers that are present/can be found from the website [link]http://www.apptrace.com/. My solution is to repeatedly change the query in the search page containing only a single character starting from a-z and having all the special characters and numbers . Is there a better method?

Comment: @OliverW Do you have a better method for the above problem to scrape all app names and developer names.

Comment: @aamir23, no, your method is how I'd go about it as well. Mind you, you'll have many doubles because their app search tries matches anywhere in the appname, so a an app named "AB" will appear both in searches "A" as well as in "B". Good luck though.

Comment: @OliverW. Yes I considered that and I guess once I have the data loaded into a csv file I can then use R to remove duplicates comparatively easily. Another solution that i came to know about is to get the information directly by making use of app meta data which is to be extracted from a different source and use it to get the App data from the apptrace website. However I highly doubt its effectiveness because the eventually we still need to use their search function which limits it to 100 results each time. What do you think?

Comment: @OliverW. Also I decided to have a pool of common app words like [app,HD,fun,free,lite.....]etc so that would speed up the process and I would probably just go up to 3-4 random characters like [abcd,bcde....]etc that should encompass all or maximal results along with numeric combinations

Answer (score 1):

The data from the graph can be easily obtained if you have the correct URL. You can find this address rather easily with e.g. the "developer tools" in firefox (check the "Network" tab for the XHR requests).

You'll see calls are being made to e.g.:

```
src = 'http://www.apptrace.com/api/app/389801252/rankings/country/?country=CAN&start_date=2014-08-08&end_date=&device=iphone&list_type=normal&chart_subtype=iphone'
```

If you call it, you'll be served a JSON reply which you can easily load into python:

```
import json
import urllib

>>> data = urllib.urlopen(src).read()
>>> reply = json.loads(data)
>>> ranks = reply['rankings'][0]['ranks']
>>> res = {'date': [], 'rank': []}
>>> for d in ranks:
...     res['date'].append(d['date'])
...     res['rank'].append(d['rank'])
... 
>>> res['date'][:3]
[u'2014-08-08', u'2014-08-09', u'2014-08-10']
>>> res['rank'][:3]
[10, 14, 13]
```

You can then store the data into a csv using python's builtin [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a link for reference. It depends how the graph is stored and displayed. Judging by it being dynamic like a stock ticker there should be some text between some tags you can grab somewhere. I have looked at examples of obtaining images and other content from websites using beautiful soup so its not impossible.

Yesterday I was working on formatting the data into CSV format and got some really useful responses pronto.

Check it out:[How can I format every other line to be merged with the line before it? (In Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869089/how-can-i-format-every-other-line-to-be-merged-with-the-line-before-it-in-pyth)

Also something I learnt here is if you will need to harvest that data often a good way to run scripts automatically is CRON jobs.

Comment: Here's the link of the chart I am trying to scrap. Any help would be appreciated. I know how to scrape text and links but this is the first time I am dealing with charts.

Comment: `<path class="nv-path-142" d="M215.82660433496054,-10L215.82660433492515,280L248.20059498517463,280.0000000001164L248.20059498519092,-10.000000000116415Z"></path>` All the co ordinates are like that which makes me think because of the complexity they might be generated by some server side scripting. Rather than the values being stored as 5,10,15,20 in convenient plots points representative of the data it seems theres heaps of large numbers representing pixel points.